# Add a condition to a form datasource with OR on two columns

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have to build a specialized form which queries the `InventTrans` table for some purchase transactions.

The transactions must be selected, either with a non-empty Voucher, either with a non-empty Packing slip Id (`PackingSlipId`).

While looking how to specify this in a query range, I found that it was possible to associate this query range to the `RecId` of the table. Is this the usual and classic way to do this ? See my example (which seem to work).

```
   QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
   ;

   qbds =  this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(inventTrans));

   sysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds, fieldNum(InventTrans, RecId)).value(
    strfmt('(%1 != "") || (%2 != "")',
            fieldstr(InventTrans, Voucher),
            fieldstr(InventTrans, PackingSlipId)));
```

Comment: I've seen it done exactly this way, and I never felt right about it, but AFAIK for what you need, it's pretty much the only way to do it with a `Query` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called range expressions and is the only way to state more complex queries with a `Query` object - see [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/aa893981(v=ax.50).aspx)

In addition have a look at [this Axaptapedia page](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges) (thanks to [FH-Inway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2720554/fh-inway))

Regarding if it is the classical way: No - only use it if necessary

Comment: Axaptapedia also has a nice article on this [topic](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges) with more details and examples which I always found helpful when working with query expressions.

Comment: Good point -almost forgot about that side as time went by :) Will add it to the answer